reassemble split files from separate zip files
I have a very large file split into smaller chucks (..zip.001,zip.002,zip.003..etc). There are a total of 2300 split files. These split files are stored in 4 separate zip files. Right now, to reassemble the files into 1, I first unzip the 4 zip files and then reassemble them using 7zip. Is there a way reassemble them directly from the 4 zip files without having to unzip all 4 zip files first?

No, there isn't. It can't guess what you want.


I'm not sure if 7zip supports split archives, even though it can
create ones.

You MIGHT need to have the "2300 files" in the same place.

Generally the FIRST file has to be named as you would normally, e.g.   "archive.zip", the second "archive.001", the third "archive.002" and so on.

At least WinRar should be able to handle such set of part-files properly.


The four larger files, MIGHT match the above.
